# In a django model, provide a set of default set of fields but also allow users to add their own

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

Not the most descriptive title, I know, but my question is much better illustrated with an example.

Let's say I'm making an application that will allow student drivers to log their driving time. They are required to log day time and night time, so I provide both fields by default. But let's say for the sake of argument that one curious teenager decides he wants to track the time he spends while driving in thunderstorms as well. And another one decides he wants to track how much time he spends driving in snow.  What is the best way of making this possible using Django?

This is a rough outline of how I'm thinking about this now. Assume this is in `models.py`:

```py
class Trip(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()

class DrivingTime(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(AcceptableTimeType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hours = models.TimeField()

class AcceptableTimeType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    # null/blank if visible for everyone
    # otherwise, should link to the user that wants this specific type of time tracked
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

I pre-set the list of default types of time (day/night in this example) in the Django admin and leave the User field blank. A user can then add any type of time that they'd like (e.g. rain or snow). Then, when I create a list of those time fields that the user can fill in, I select the subset of `AcceptableTypeTime` items that are either linked to the current field or are null.

It seems like this should work, but I also feel like there should be a common solution to this problem that I may be completely unaware of.  Any pointers in the right direction would be most appreciated!

Comment: and what about user who wants to record hours by night, under a thunderstorn with snow, on a lava road ? the tag should be multiple or unique ?

Comment: A quick look isn't yielding a well-maintained, current leader as far as libraries for Django, but you should probably look into a simple 'tag' model to hook up to `DrivingTime` records. Allowing users to specify arbitrary tags, which may or may not already exist, is a normal pattern that can probably help you here. There are certain ways to simulate user-triggered schema changes, but they're almost always an indication that you should be stepping back to re-evaluate your approach rather than going into something like EAV or JSON fields.